# function calling itself with setInterval (browser freezing issue)

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I know there already are similar questions to mine but none of the answers I read solved my problem.

I wrote a small script that prints a string letter by letter using two functions : first one spells the string, second one calls the first using `setInterval` as long as the word isn't entirely spelled :

```
function write() {
  writeThis = str.substring(0, currentLetter);
  div.innerHTML = writeThis;
  currentLetter++;
  console.log('running'); 
}

function start() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if (currentLetter > str.length) {
        return false;
    }
    write(); //calls the writing function
  }, 100);
}
start();
```

I need to merge these two functions into one in order to dynamically use it on different strings by passing the strings as a parameter. I'm trying to do something like this :

```
function write(thisString) {
  //code
  return thisString;
}
var str1 = "hello world";
var str2 = "foo bar";
write(str1); write(str2);
```

I'm stuck when it comes to insert `setInterval` in `write()` function to call itself. No matter what I try `write()` will just call itself forever (despite the `if` condition) and freeze the browser. Is it possible to merge these two functions into one ?

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/Hal_9100/b5gm8nbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` will keep firing until you call `clearInterval(intervalId)`.

For most animation, it's easier to control with `setTimeout` in any case, as follows:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var str = 'hello world.';
var currentLetter = 1;

var writeThis = str.substring(0, currentLetter);

function write() {
    writeThis = str.substring(0, currentLetter);
    div.innerHTML = writeThis;
    currentLetter++;
    console.log('running'); 
}

function run(){
    if (currentLetter > str.length) {
        return false;
    }
    write();
    setTimeout(run, 100);
}

function start() {
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}
start();
```

If you really want to use `setInterval`, the function returns the intervalId you need, so you'd do something like:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(fn, 100);
```

then in the if statement, you'd call

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

Obviously, you need to make sure `intervalId` is in scope in both places.

** EDIT **

Adding making it one function.  Sorry I missed that part of the question. The trick here is to use `Function.bind()`

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var str = 'hello world.';
var currentLetter = 1;

var writeThis = str.substring(0, currentLetter);

function run(text){
    if (currentLetter > text.length) {
        return false;
    }
    writeThis = text.substring(0, currentLetter);
    div.innerHTML = writeThis;
    currentLetter++;
    console.log('running');
    setTimeout(run.bind(null, text), 100);
}

run(str);
```

If you wanted to pass in everything (e.g. the div, the str, the current letter), just add them as params to the `run` function and add them when you bind again.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation makes things clearer. However that doesn't solve my problem merging my 2 functions (3 with your suggestion) into one.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm ! Didn't know of this function.bind() method, will ddefinitely use it on further projects !

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample prototype to use `Element.typeEffect("Hello World");`

**Update**: it's better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` to write string as text not HTML.

**Points:**

- Avoid to use increasing number as global variable if you want to use the function with multiple divs
- Your `#div` should be empty before you use this function.
- You can use callback to be fired after finish writing.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

Element.prototype.typeEffect = function(str, onfinish) {
  var el = this;
  var i = el.textContent || el.innerText;
  i = i.length;
  if (i == str.length) {
    if (typeof onfinish == "function") onfinish();
    return;
  }

  el.textContent += str[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    el.typeEffect(str, onfinish);
  }, 100);

}

div.typeEffect("Hello World");
//optinaly callback
div2.typeEffect("Helo Again", function() {
  console.log("#div2 finished");
});
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

If you dislike prototypes try this

```
function typeEffect(str,el,cb) {
  var i = el.textContent || el.innerText;
  i = i.length;
  if (i == str.length){
  if(typeof cb == "function")cb();
    return;    
  }
  el.textContent += str[i];
  setTimeout(function() {
    typeEffect(str,el,cb);
  }, 100);

}
//usage
typeEffect("Hello World",div);
//or with callback
typeEffect("Hello World",div,function(){
console.log("finished");
});
```

Comment: this Mozilla Page talks about the differences between textcontent, innerHTML, and innerText: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Glad to help :) . callback option added.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setInterval()`, you have to clear the interval with `clearInterval()`.

The **structure**:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var i = 0;
    if(i < x) {
        ...
    } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

**In total:**

```js
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var str = "Hello world!";

function write(str) {
  var i = 0;
  var len = str.length;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < len) {
      div.innerHTML += str[i];
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i += 1;
  }, 100);
}

write(str);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```